# Inversion applied on circles

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles, inversive-geometry

I'm studying for my exam and one of the questions I am stuck on is:

> Show that under inversion in the unit circle a circle with centre C and radius $S$ inverts into a circle with centre $\frac{C}{C\overline{C} - s^2}$ and radius $\frac{s}{C\overline{C} - s^2}$.

And I know:
$$Z\overline{Z}-Z\overline{C}-\overline{Z}C+C\overline{C}-s^2=0$$

Can someone please explain how to do this question?

Comment: What is $Z$ mapped to under inversion in the unit circle?

Comment: I don't know?? :(

Comment: What is, geometrically, the inversion in the unit circle?

Comment: is that i...? or what is it?

Comment: Inversion in a circle is a map. Can you describe that map geometrically?

Comment: Sorry I know you're trying to help, but I'm getting more confused.

Comment: Does [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) help a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inversion is

$$z\mapsto \frac1{\bar z}$$

Your equation for the circle is basically the squared form of

$$ \lvert z - C\rvert = s $$

Now combine them:

\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\frac1{\bar z}-C\right\rvert&=s \\
\left(\frac1{\bar z}-C\right)\left(\frac1{z}-\bar C\right)&=s^2 \\
\frac1{z\bar z}-\frac{C}{z}-\frac{\bar C}{\bar z}+C\bar C-s^2&=0 \\
1-C\bar z -\bar Cz+z\bar z\left(C\bar C-s^2\right) &= 0 \\
z\bar z - \frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\bar z - \overline{\left(\frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)}z + \frac{1}{C\bar C-s^2} &= 0
\\
\left(z-\frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right) 
\left(\bar z-\frac{\bar C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)
-\frac{C\bar C}{\left(C\bar C-s^2\right)^2}
+\frac{C\bar C-s^2}{\left(C\bar C-s^2\right)^2}
&= 0
\\
\left(z-\frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right) 
\left(\bar z-\frac{\bar C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)
-\left(\frac{s}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)^2
&= 0
\\
\left(z-\frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right) 
\left(\bar z-\frac{\bar C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)
&= \left(\frac{s}{C\bar C-s^2}\right)^2
\\
\left\lvert z-\frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2}\right\rvert
&= \frac{s}{C\bar C-s^2}
\end{align*}

From this you can read

\begin{align*}
C' &= \frac{C}{C\bar C-s^2} &
s' &= \frac{s}{C\bar C-s^2}
\end{align*}

as expected.

Comment: MvG, I feel like you always help me out in this class. I wish you could tutor me ;-;

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: MvG, I was wondering if I have a circle C and radius r and centre o = (1,1), how does that change things? I have to find the radius of the circle C' (in terms of r) which is the image of C after inversion in the unit circle about the origin.

Comment: @JayC: I don't understand your question. Simply apply the above formulas, I don't see why anything should change. Except for the fact that in the above formulas, $C$ is the center and $s$ the radius, instead of center $o$ and radius $r$. And you'd have to write $o=1+i$ instead of $o=(1,1)$, obviously. In any case, I don't feel much inclined to answer new questions unless you start accepting those answers which did help you, as you claim they did.